Angular Material: Localize and LuxonDateAdapter
I try to use luxon for localization of the DatePickers. The main reason for this is that this adapter provides the utc functionality and is NOT deprecated.
According to the documentation I should use in the provider provideLuxonDateAdapter or MatLuxonDateModule.
I have now included (still in the @NgModule):
providers: [
        {provide: MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true, firstDayOfWeek: 1}},
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: LuxonDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_LUXON_DATE_FORMATS},

and this works well - without using the function provideLuxonDateAdapter.
I don't find a clear hint if I need this function or not. Any hints in which situations I need the one and/or the other?

You can just check what this function does in the source code here. As you can see, it more or less does exactly the same thing.

Ahh - I see. So the provideLuxonDateAdapter sets up the basics and the options are the rest. Thx for clarification.
